# Env Implementation of in Angular 9

Tags: angular, dotenv

Is there any way to hide API credentials in Angular?

I tried to implement the code in my project and it seems that this not work properly,
I don't know if this is compatible with angular 9, I followed the steps and still I got an error.

Please see the link and my sample code below,
https://www.ninadsubba.in/blog/setup-dotenv-to-access-environment-variables-in-angular-9

> [image]
>
> **environment.ts**

> [image]
>
> **.env**

[image]

> **Terminal Output**

I already installed the following package:
**npm install --save-dev yargs dotenv** and **npm install @types/node --save-dev** and still this error appear, please helped me to resolve this issue to clearly understand how dotenv can be useful to hide credentials in angular, or if this only works on node.js, sorry guys I'm very new in angular. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dotenv` is more like a configuration container for constants and it doesn't hide your (sensitive) data at runtime. It's widely used with Nodejs to load constants to process.env file (but there are some workarounds for ng-cli, also). The best way it would be to get sensitive data by consuming an API endpoint.

Comment: WHat kind of credentials do you want to hide exactly? If it's something like a google maps API key (to display the map) or any other static key that the front needs to communicated with a 3rd party service, then you cannot hide it. Otherwise, if it's a key used for server to server communication, add that key to your API instead

Comment: let say i have some endpoint and I want it to hide,
like what we put in environment.ts,

Is there a way to not show this when we publish the project? like run in the browser?

Comment: we all know that browser have its developer tools where you can check/inspect your code, but one thing that I'm concerned is that how can i hide also the webpack, so that they couldn't get take a peek to my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obfuscate code to make it harder to read using settings in webpack (I believe it is done by default).

[The article you mentioned](https://www.ninadsubba.in/blog/setup-dotenv-to-access-environment-variables-in-angular-9) is very misleading and dangerous and implies that you can "hide" credentials from the user on their own machine. To quote the article:

> "Googling for help on setting up environment variables for Angular is a nightmare;"

**There is a very good reason that this is the case!!**

> **anything** you give to the client, can be read by them. You cannot hide it.

This means that if you need an api key to access your api, then they **will** see this.

Remember, if you need to communicate with your api, you'll send an http request with authorization headers, these will *always* appear in plain text in the network tab for everyone who uses your Angular app.

**A potential solution** would be to change how you authenticate. Instead of using a key, authenticate your users against your api (A well respected practice is using OAuth)
Here is a good [package for angular oauth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-oauth2-oidc). This allows users to send a username/password combo (or use a third party provider) to exchange this for a token that they can then send back and forth with your server to authenticate their api requests. Your server should *always* verify the integrity of this token when receiving a request. [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) is also a commonly used resource for dealing with authentication so you don't have to.